# How accurately can a irrational algebraic number represent a different irrational number compared to a rational approximation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

If I am trying to approximate $x = \sqrt D$ such that D is a square free integer I can use [Diophantine approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) and the [Fundamental Recurrence Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_recurrence_formulas) to find a rational approximation $\dfrac{a}{b}$ for $\sqrt D$ to a given accuracy $M$ where $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ and $|a|, |b| \le M$.  I noticed that [Hurwitz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29) gives an upper bound for these approximations to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 5b^2}$ and the [Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Lagrange_spectrum)/[Markov spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_spectrum) demonstrates an improved upper bound of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 8b^2}$ if irrational numbers [equivalent to $\phi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Equivalent_real_numbers) the golden ratio are excluded.

So, if I instead use $a, b \in \mathbb Z[\phi]$ and $a$ and $b$ are still bounded by $M$, how much more accurate an approximation can I get given some $M$?  How would I go about finding good values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: since $\mathbb Z[\phi]$ has a euclidean algorithm - you might be able to directly compute the (periodic?) continued fraction of quadratic irrationals over $\mathbb Z[\phi]$ instead of the usual $\mathbb Z$. We would need to re-prove the results about best rational approximations and it's not clear what the golden equivalent of the Farey sequence is.